# How to find the different lines between 2 files in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm working on a small PHP application which update a stock products regularly, i'm getting the updated file from the server, and i have the old one in my directory, so what is the best way to get only the updated products(lines) between these two files, for information both files contain arround 70000 product lines.

I though to store the data of each file into an array, then use "array_diff" to compare them, it will work theoretically, but will be good idea with 70000 on each array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't a command line `diff` do it?

Comment: 70,000 is not that much, but that also depends on the information on each line. I would normally use a database to hold the data, read in the new file and compare it against the database. This way you can also store the history, and see when something changed and by how much.

Comment: Using database was my idea too, but my project manager, told me that he doesn't want to go with this solution he wants, the program just to retrieve the new flat file data, compare to the last one, detect the changes line (10 lines has been changed for example), and then send these lines to another program using it's API

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `diff` command.
For reference: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diff-command-linux-examples/

Comment: diff is a linux command, wil it work in a windows enviroment?
Because i'm developping in local currently using xampp